# How do I get value on a specific row on html table using modal and php

Tags: php, html, mysql, modal-dialog

I have a table that list Employee Leave record and status. Each record has a unique leave id. I want to view each row's leave id and status by clicking the 'View' modal button. However, all buttons display the first row data from the database. How do I make each button corresponds to its leave id number on every row. Please help. I'm super newbie here. LOL. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
      <h2>Employee Leaves</h2>
<?php

$mysql_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_password ="";
$mysql_database = "employeerecord";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password, $mysql_database);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sqli = "SELECT emp_id, leave_id, last_name, first_name, leave_type, start_date, end_date, comment, date_filed, time_filed, status FROM leaves";
$result = $conn->query($sqli);


if ($result->num_rows > 0) { ?>
    <table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID Number</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Leave Type</th>
            <th>Start Date</th>
            <th>End Date</th>
            <th>Comment</th>
            <th>Date Filed</th>
            <th>Time Filed</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Leave ID</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<?php
    // output data of each row

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    { ?>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $row["emp_id"]; ?>   
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $row["last_name"]; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $row["first_name"]; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $row["leave_type"]; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $row["start_date"]; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $row["end_date"]; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $row["comment"]; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $row["date_filed"]; ?>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $row["time_filed"]; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $row["status"]; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                <?php 
                $leavestatus = $row["status"];
                $leaveid = $row["leave_id"]; 
                echo $leaveid; 
                ?>
                </td>
                <td>
        <button type="button" name="<?php $leaveid; ?>" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">View</button>
            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Update Leave</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>Leave ID:<?php echo $leaveid; ?></p>
                        <p>Leave Status:<?php echo $leavestatus; ?></p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    <?php }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your modals have the same id. So the first one will get called when any button is clicked. Try this:

```
<button type="button" name="<?php echo $leaveid; ?>" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal-<?php echo $leaveid; ?>">View</button>
```

(also, you are missing the echo statement on your button name)

and

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal-<?php echo $leaveid; ?>" role="dialog">
```

Or better yet, just have one modal that is outside the loop and use jQuery to populate it when any button is clicked.

Comment: You're a life saver sir! That work! Thank you so much. Btw, jQuery is not yet in our topic but will surely use that soon. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 1):

First, put the tbody tag outside that while loop:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    { ?>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $row["emp_id"]; ?>   
                </td>
                <td>   
              </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    <?php }
```

should be:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
        { ?>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $row["emp_id"]; ?>   
                    </td>
                    <td>   
                  </td>
                </tr>

        <?php }
```

Also the ID of the modal needs to match the property of the button revealing it:

```
<button type="button" name="<?php $leaveid; ?>" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal_<?php $leaveid; ?>">View</button>
            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal_<?php $leaveid; ?>" role="dialog">
```

Give that a shot!

Best of Luck!

Comment: This one worked too. Yes, the modal id is the problem. I see it now. Thank you so much for your help.